# Read local JSON file from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying a read a static json file which has cloudwatch logs in it and that same json file is stored on my local machine , now i want to write a lambda function which will read that json file and fetch the logs as output

Comment: Look at storing the JSON file in an Amazon S3 bucket. A Lambda function running in the cloud cannot read files stored on your local dev machine.

Comment: If you want to serve files from your local machine to a Lambda function (or any client outside of your local network) then you are going to have to provide a path into your network from outside, via your local firewall(s), and run a file server of some description (e.g. SFTP) on your local machine. It's better to place this file on S3 and give the Lambda function permission to retrieve it from there. Or package it with the uploaded Lambda function.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If you package your log file with your lambda code (or add it in the AWS console to the lambda), you will be able to access it directly.

Then you can open it with the usual usage of open.

Another option will be to use S3 and boto3.